# What is a good way to access URL's via QR codes with the Hololens?

Tags: augmented-reality, qr-code, hololens

I have been researching this a bit and it seems there are tons of different ways and plugins for this.
What I want to do is:

- scan a QR code via the Hololens 2 (I know that this works with the MixedRealityToolkit)
- open the URL the QR code links the user to
- browse through the website

From the examples I saw on the internet, it seems like you can scan QR codes, but it just shows you the
data saved on the code. It doesn't redirect you to the website.
Do plugins like this one https://developer.vuplex.com/webview/overview allow you to be redirected to the website after scanning the QR code?

I appreciate any help, I thought maybe somebody has experience with this already.

I looked into all of the possibilites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About QR code, you can refer to [QR code tracking overview - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/qr-code-tracking-overview) and [microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample at OpenXR (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-QRCode-Sample/tree/OpenXR).

After you get the URL by scanning the QR code, you can use [LaunchUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-22621) to open the URL in browser. For more information, please refer to [Launch the default app for a URI - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app). It should be noted that using WinRT API in Unity needs to add preprocessor directives, please refer to [Unity - Manual: WinRT API in C# scripts for UWP (unity3d.com)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html).

Regarding the WebView mentioned in the link you provided, you can refer to [HoloLens 2 release notes | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-23h1---june-2023-update), the WebView 2 preview is already available in the latest update. But note that this feature is still in preview state, and there are some known issues, please refer to [Get started with WebView2 in HoloLens 2 Unity apps (Preview) - Microsoft Edge Development | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/hololens2) for more information. If you are interested in this feature, please keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thank you so much this was really helpful, do you know if I can use qr-codes to place objects at the correct place in ar?